# Is there any better way to find any string from multiple string array

Tags: java, string, arraylist

In the below example, there are some predefined array of String, that i have mentioned in below example, Now my requirement is if the boName prensents in each array i need to call the methods defined for particular custom fileds. Is there any other way to avoid multiple for loops.

```
public class MyClass {

    private static final String[] OTHER_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H" };
    private static final String[] TRANSACTION_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME = { "A", "AB", "CD", "DE", "EG" };
    private static final String[] CRM_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME = { "I", "J", "K", "L", "M" };
    private static final String[] ITEM_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME = { "N", "O", "P", "Q" };
    private static final String[] ENTITY_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME = { "AN", "ZY", "X", "P" };

    public static List<String> BusinessObjectDescribe(String boName) {
        List<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (boName != null && !boName.isEmpty()) {
            for (String string : OTHER_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME) {
                if (boName.equals(string)) {
                    fields.addAll(getOtherCustomFields());
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (String string : TRANSACTION_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME) {
                if (boName.equals(string)) {
                    fields.addAll(getTransactionCustomFields());
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (String string : CRM_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME) {
                if (boName.equals(string)) {
                    fields.addAll(getCRMCustomFields());
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (String string : ITEM_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME) {
                if (boName.equals(string)) {
                    fields.addAll(getITEMCustomFields());
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (String string : ENTITY_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME) {
                if (boName.equals(string)) {
                    fields.addAll(getEntityCustomFields());
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        return fields;

    }

}
```

Comment: There are many ways to do efficient string searching

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java8 you can use advantage of functional interfaces. Just create new function which gets your array as a first param and suplier function as a second. In suplier you can pass your logic regarding add. And you need to call that funtion multiple times instead of duplicate code.

Answer (score 1):

To search, you can use the following in java-8:

```
Arrays.stream(OTHER_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME)
    .filter(e -> e.contains("A"))
    .findFirst();
```

Here we convert the array as a stream and then apply a filter. If a match is found it will return the element else it will return `null`. Also, `.findFirst()` will stop searching the stream as soon as a match is found.

You can use the same syntax and search the other arrays as desired.

Comment: It's best to explain what this code does. OP might not be familiar with Java 8 features.

Comment: Agreed and edited. (Actually was editing it before your comment :-)

Comment: and then you can use map to collect the result, and pass id to addAll:
                fields.addAll(
Arrays.stream(OTHER_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME)
                        .filter(e -> e.contains("A"))
                        .findFirst()
                        .map(s -> getOtherCustomFields()).orElse(Collections.EMPTY_LIST))
                ;

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a class that encapsulates the behavior you perform in the loop.

```
class MyClass {
    class BoNameHandler {
        private Collection<String> applicableNames;
        private Supplier<Collection<String>> getter;
        BoNameHandler(String[] names, Supplier<Collection<String>> g) {
            applicableNames = Arrays.asList(names);
            getter = g;
        }
        void addIfApplicable(String boName, List<String> addTo) {
            if (applicableNames.stream().filter(boName::equals).findFirst().isPresent()) {
                addTo.addAll(getter.get());
            }
        }
    }
    List<BoNameHandler> handlers = new ArrayList<>();
    MyClass() {
        handlers.add(new BoNameHandler(OTHER_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME, this::getOtherCustomFields));
        handlers.add(new BoNameHandler(TRANSACTION_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME, this::getTransactionCustomFields));
        // and the others
    }
}
```

This will reduce your code to

```
public static List<String> BusinessObjectDescribe(String boName) {
    List<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (BoNameHandler handler : handlers) {
        handler.addIfApplicable(boName, fields);
    }
    return fields;
}
```

I don't know what your methods look like, but if they're as fixed as the BO_NAMEs, you might just as well put them together in one `enum` though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you please explain about Supplier<Collection<String>> getter?? is this from jjava.util.function.Supplier??

Comment: @AmrendraKumar Yes, that is a `java.util.function.Supplier`. It means that it is a method that takes no arguments and returns a collection of `String`s (as your `getXXX()` methods seem to do).

Comment: I am getting error on this  handlers.add(new BoNameHandler(OTHER_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME, this::getOtherCustomFields)); Do i need to change the second parameter of the constructor to Object???

Comment: @AmrendraKumar That depends on the error you get. You might need to change the getter member and constructor to `BoNameHandler(String[] names, Supplier<List<String>> g)`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, If understand your code, all the methods will be called upfront only, but my requirement is, if boName matches, then only i will call the methods, because in each method there is REST api call based on match.

Answer (score 0):

As `Set`, the mathematical set `{ a, b, c }`, in fact is the most logical data structure, use that.

```
private static final Set<String> OTHER_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME =
    Set.of( "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H" );
private static final Set<String> TRANSACTION_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME =
    Set.of( "A", "AB", "CD", "DE", "EG" );
private static final Set<String> CRM_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME =
    Set.of( "I", "J", "K", "L", "M" );
private static final Set<String> ITEM_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME =
    Set.of( "N", "O", "P", "Q" );
private static final Set<String> ENTITY_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME =
    Set.of( "AN", "ZY", "X", "P" );


public static List<String> BusinessObjectDescribe(String boName) {
    List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    if (boName != null && !boName.isEmpty()) {
        if (OTHER_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME.contains(boName)) {
            fields.addAll(getOtherCustomFields());
        }
        if (TRANSACTION_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME.contains(boName)) {
            fields.addAll(getTransactionCustomFields());
        }
        if (CRM_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME.contains(boName)) {
            fields.addAll(getCRMCustomFields());
        }
        if (ITEM_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME.contains(boName)) {
            fields.addAll(getITEMCustomFields());
        }
        if (ENTITY_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME.contains(boName)) {
            fields.addAll(getEntityCustomFields());
        }
    }
    return fields;
}
```

If your java version still does not know `Set.of` *(before java 9)* do:

```
private static final Set<String> OTHER_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME = new HashSet<>();
static {
    Collections.addAll(OTHER_CUSTOM_FIELD_RELATED_BO_NAME,
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H" );
}
```

`Set` is the fastest data structure. So why *not* take the best.

Comment: Will be helpful to point out that this will work with java 9+

Comment: @NicholasK below was added a pre-9 solution: _"if your java version still..."_, but thanks; I'll add the version number.

Answer (score 0):

I would also think about putting all those arrays to one Map, or Map, and process it afterwards.